# How to integrate My public Domain website with Salesforce?

Tags: html, salesforce

I want to integrate my company website with salesforce.com. How can I do this?

Comment: We could probably help point you in the right direction if you told us what you mean by "integrate my website with salesforce.com." What *exactly* do you want to do?

Comment: Voting to close - this was completely and obviously unanswerable seven years ago, and still is today.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the web-to-lead feature for capturing leads on your site, here's the info:

"To start capturing Leads from your Web site, go to Setup -> Customize --> Leads --> Web-to-Lead."
http://www.salesforce.com/community/crm-implementation/custom-lead-functionality.jsp